# Read/Write an Ext4 SD card

Tags: android-sdcard, ext4

I am a dual-boot Windows7 + Ubuntu 15.04 user. I want to access an Ext4 SD card(primarily to backup my android marshmallow data), But the SD card is inaccessible in Windows 7 for which I tried ext2fsd but it doesn't assign a drive letter to removable disks (this has a been a problem for a while). 
Ubuntu doesn't even read the SD card. I might be able to access via terminal, but I am unaware of the commands.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that each and every SD card is formatted to only work with the one phone that you have used it with.
So even a ext4 supporting linux OS wouldn't be able to read/write from it.
Oh well...